# Изменение Hamburger кнопки на back arrow fragment

Tags: android

Добрый день. У меня есть Главное `Activity`, в нём есть `DrawerLayout` и 3 фрагмента. С 3-его фрагмента есть переход на 4-ый фрагмент, в котором требуется отключить `DrawerLayout`, убрать "Гамбургер кнопку" и сделать Back-Arrow кнопку к возврату на 3-ий. Переход с 3 Фрагмента на 4 и обратно происходят нормально, `DrawerLayout` работает, но после перехода с 4 на 3, "Гамбургер" кнопка работает некорректно. Какой бы фрагмент не был в данный момент загружен, при нажатии на "Гамбургер" кнопку всегда происходит переход на 3-ий фрагмент. Никак не могу разобраться, где проблема. Вроде бы не назначал ей ничего такого..

```
 mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {    

                //Отключаю "Гамбургер" кнопку
                MainActivity.toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
                //Создаю транзакцию
                FragmentTransaction ftrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                addFilterFrag = new AddFilterFrag();
                //Меняю местами, addFilterFrag - 4ый Фрагмент
                ftrans.replace(R.id.content_frame, addFilterFrag);
                ftrans.addToBackStack(null);
                ftrans.commit();

            }
        });
```

Происходит переход на 4-ый Фрагмент - `addFilterFrag`. Здесь, в методе `onCreate()` я отключаю `DrawerLayout`:

```
MainActivity.drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
```

А в методе `onCreateView()` вызываю `ToolBar` из `MainActivity`, делаю иконку на тулбаре и присваиваю ей действие перехода обратно, на 3-ий фрагмент.

```
  MainActivity.toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.back_icon);
            MainActivity.toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                 public void onClick(View v) {
//Возобновляю работу "Гамбургер" кнопки:
                    MainActivity.toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);

                    FragmentTransaction ftrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    filterFrag = new FilterFrag();
                    ftrans.replace(R.id.content_frame, filterFrag);
                    //Включаю работу DrawerLayout
MainActivity.drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
                    ftrans.commit();
                }});
```

Comment: С какой ошибкой и на какой строчке крашится? Это обязательная информация без кое помочь вам практически невозможно.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб я изменил вопрос, переходы заработали, но теперь есть другая проблема. Посмотрите пожалуйста.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб похоже, проблема кроется в том, что "Hamburger button" исполняет роль ToolBar`a, которого я подключил в 4-ом Фрагменте. Нужно как-то отключить его и возобновить обычную работу Hamburget Button`a

Comment: Икноку и setNavigationOnClickListener не надо самому ставить. Достаточно setDrawerIndicatorEnabled. обрабатывать нажатие на стрелку/гамбургер надо в onOptionsItemSelected. Подробнее никак - слишком много нюансов.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Да вот в том и дело, что уж слишком много нюансов. Разбирал более 30 тем на SO, но почему-то у меня ничего не работает даже приблизительно, кроме моего кода(который выше написал). Пробовал вызывать переопределять `getActivity().onBackPressed` и вызывать во фрагментах и т.д. но что-то ничего не работает..

Comment: @ЮрийСПб тогда другой вопрос, если обработка происходит в `onOptionsItemSelected`, нужно же сначала вывести стрелку назад в тулбаре. Как это сделать правильно? SetHomeUpEnable у меня не работает...

Comment: По идее надо просто `toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false)`;

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Я так и сделал, но где-то здесь кроется ловушка, потому что гамбургер кнопка начинает работать неправильно)

Comment: Неправильно - это как?

Comment: но после перехода с 4 на 3, "Гамбургер" кнопка работает некорректно. Какой бы фрагмент не был в данный момент загружен, при нажатии на "Гамбургер" кнопку всегда происходит переход на 3-ий фрагмент. Никак не могу разобраться, где проблема. Вроде бы не назначал ей ничего такого..
Я в вопросе это написал.

Comment: Ну так вы ж в определённый момент жестко меняете поведение сей кнопки и потом не отменяете. Вот оно и открывает вам всегда один и тот же фрагмент...

Answer (score 1):

```
 toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });
```